# Define piecewise function with variables defined in modulus

Tags: function-construction

I would like to define a function $f$ as follows:

$$
f(p)=p^2-2p,\qquad (p\equiv3\pmod4)
$$
and $f(p)=0$ otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: `f[p_Integer] /; Mod[p, 4] == 3 := (* stuff *)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completing the comment with catch-all rule.

```
f[p_Integer] := p^2 - 2 p /; Mod[p, 4] == 3

f[_] := 0

f /@ Range[-5, 5]
```

> {35, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0}